# how to import mongo db in vue js 2?

Tags: mongodb, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i already have try to install mongodb via npm  but i keep getting error Cannot find module "fs"

and my code is look like this

```js
<script>
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 export default {
  data(){
   return{
    msg:'this is a test'
   }
  },
  created:function(){
   MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', (err, database) => {
    if (err){
     console.log('1');
    }else{
     console.log('2');
    }
   })
  }
 }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
 <div>
  {{msg}}
 </div>
</template>
```

so how do i import mongodb to my vuejs 2 framework?

Comment: Vue runs in the browser. MongoDB runs on a server, it cannot run in a browser. What you are trying is technically impossible. Instead, you have to setup a web server (with expressjs, for example) which accesses MongoDB, and then communicate with between browser and server via AJAX.

Comment: got it, but my question is how to send data and receive data from mongodb? i know how to do this with express but i am new to vuejs.

Comment: You don't access mongodb from Vue code. You send AJAX/REST requests to your express server, which acesses mongodv and sends the result back to the client. You do so with any AJAX lib you want. I like to use axios. a nice tutotial can be found here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VueJS is frontend framework.

You definitely should not try to deal with DB directly from Vue.

You should have backend made with any language/framework you want: NodeJS(if you want to stick with JS), ASP.NET(C#), Spring(Java) etc. and your backend should deal with DB and you should only make AJAX requests to your backend and send/get back JSONs and deal with JSONs on frontend with Vue.